# I can't import csv file

Tags: r, csv, import

I couldn't import data in R. There are some Korean character on first row(head?).
I think that's the problem, but I don't know how to handle this.

my code:

```r
df1 <- read.csv("dangchum.csv")
```

Console message:

> **"Invalid multibyte string" **

Comment: Hi Magic Super. Please open the CSV file in a text editor and edit your question to include the first few rows.

Comment: May be helpful: [Invalid multibyte string in read.csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14363085/invalid-multibyte-string-in-read-csv) or [R: invalid multibyte string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4993837/17303805).

Comment: If it is just the first row and it can be discarded, can you do `df1 <- read.csv("dangchum.csv", skip = 1)`?

Answer (score 0):

Might be unicode problem, you could try to use readr package like this:

```
library(readr)
df1 <- read_csv("dangchum.csv")
```

`install.packages("readr")` if not available.

Comment: still error message appear

> library(readr)
> df1 <- read_csv("dangchum.csv")
Rows: 667 Columns: 7                                                                              
nchar(x, "width") error :invalid multibyte string, element 1

Comment: Maybe the csv file encoding dose not recognized by R. How about convert the file encoding to utf8 first and try again. And I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71532975/trying-to-read-csv-file-says-error-in-ncharx-width-invalid-multibyte-s) might be helpful

Comment: Try `df1 <- read_csv("dangchum.csv", locale=locale(encoding="latin1"))` in the call to read_csv